# Editar imagem adicionando uma moldura com IONIC

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic

com o cordova-plugin-camera eu já consigo tirar uma foto e manipular o local do arquivo, mas existe algum outro plugin ou método para aplicar algo a foto, como uma moldura?

**1 -** Tiro uma foto

**2 -** Manipulo a foto adicionando, por cima dela, uma janela e salvando no dispositivo a imagem editada.

Se isso não é possível com IONIC, existe outra forma alternativa que não seja criar um plugin para cada plataforma?

### Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]